# Where is the best place to store an application setting that needs to be updated frequently in ServiceNow

Tags: servicenow

I have a scheduled script execution that needs to persist a value between runs. It is updated with each run. Using [gs.setProperty](https://developer.servicenow.com/app.do#!/api_doc?v=kingston&id=r_SGSYS-setProperty_S_S_S) seemed like the natural place until I came across this:

> Care should be taken when setting system properties (sys_properties)
>   using this method as it causes a system-wide cache flush. Each flush
>   can cause system degradation while the caches rebuild. If a value must
>   be updated often, it should not be stored as a system property. In
>   general, you should only place values in the sys_properties table that
>   do not frequently change.

Creating a separate table to store a single scalar value seems like overkill. Is there a better place to store it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set a preference if you need it in the instance. Another place could be the events table. Log the event with the data in parm1 or parm2 and on next run query the most recent event.

I'd avoid making a table as that has cost implications for some clients.  I agree with the `sys_properties`.

```
var encrypter = new GlideEncrypter();
var encrypted = encrypter.encrypt('Super Secret Phrase');
gs.info('encrypted: ' + encrypted);
var decrypted = encrypter.decrypt(encrypted);
gs.info('decrypted: ' + decrypted);
/**
*** Script: encrypted: g/bXLJHa7xNRMKZEo5q/YtLMEdse36ED
*** Script: decrypted: Super Secret Phrase
*/
```

This way only administrators could really read this data.  Also if I recall correctly, the sysevent table is cleared after 7 days.  You could have the job remove the event as soon as it has it in memory.

Comment: Event table is a good idea but the value is sensitive. I'm surprised ServiceNow doesn't have a mechanism for frequently updated scalar values.

Comment: You can encrypt the value first. I added an example to my answer since I can't seem to add code snippets to comments